# java : NullPointerAccess (NullPointerException) in swith case

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, switch-statement

This is my code:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option;
    do{
        System.out.println("1. Add Account");
        System.out.println("2. Check Balance");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");

        System.out.print("Enter Choice >> ");
        option = in.nextInt();

        Account account = null;

        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            try{
                System.out.print("Enter id >> ");
                int id = in.nextInt(); 
                System.out.print("Enter amount >> ");
                double bal = in.nextDouble();
                account = new Account(id, bal);

            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) { 
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println(account.getBalance()); // null pointer access here
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            break;
        }

    }
    while(option!=5);
```

During run, I'm adding the account before checking the balance and hence initializing the `account` object. Still when I select option 2, I get a `NullPointerException`. Is there something special about switch case that I'm missing? What is happening to my account instance when I'm selecting option 2 after option 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `Account account = null;` to before the do loop.

Comment: This works okay.. but can you explain whats happening?

Comment: In your original code, when you press 2, you assigned null to account again, before the `switch`.